# Flex Slider going in Reverse on last slide

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider, responsive-slides

So for some reason, as you can see here:

http://icgadv.com.s159009.gridserver.com/tg-beta/

When you click on the buttons below the slider, img a, b , and c, they all correspond to their slide, but the last image button when clicked goes in the opposite direction to load the slide. I didn't see this happening on their site, nothing was changed except for some CSS and using jQuery to replace the navigation html with the images.

Any thoughts? In an ideal world this would just be a circular scroll. I don't care if it goes backwards to return to the first slide, but I don't like how it's going backwards to get the the last slide. Sorta treating it like it's the first.

Comment: I have the same question

Comment: The page gives 404. Could you add the demo here?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the following to the top of your flexslider options

   $('.flexslider').flexslider({
   **animationLoop: false,** ...
2. Or you can try to add an empty `<li></li>` at the end of your slides

Comment: Hmm, none of those options worked. Separately or together. Thanks though.